# how to get the ipaddress of a virtual box running on local machine

Tags: virtualbox, ip-address, winscp

I need to connect to my virtual box running on my local machine to transfer files from my local system to VM by using WinSCP.

How do I find the IP address?
When I go to the settings and network tab, there I find something related to IP, but when I use that, it says **cannot find** or invalid.

Comment: What is the OS of the VM?

Comment: When I start mine using vagrant, it shows the ip address on boot time. Do you have console access to the vbox so you can type command to get ip address?

Comment: Yes I have a console

Comment: Accessing your Ubuntu Virtualbox Guest from your Host OS [link]https://gist.github.com/odan/48fc744434ec6566ca9f7a993f4a7ffb

Comment: In case you want to get the ip without going to your vm you can use `VBoxManage guestproperty enumerate <vmname> | grep IP` on host machine as stated here [link] https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36592

Answer (score 98):

Login to virtual machine use below command to check ip address. (anyone will work)

1. ifconfig
2. ip addr show

If you used NAT for your virtual machine settings(your machine ip will be 10.0.2.15), then you have to use port forwarding to connect to machine. **IP address will be 127.0.0.1**

If you used bridged networking/Host only networking, then you will have separate Ip address. Use that IP address to connect virtual machine

Comment: How do I use port forwarding to connect to the machine? And why is "IP address will be 127.0.0.1"?

Comment: Please refer this site, to setup port forwarding. http://trainenv.blogspot.in/2016/03/creating-virtual-machine-in-virtual-box.html                                                                                                                       
IP Address 127.0.0.1 is by default assigned to your host machine. When connection comes to this IP, it will forward the request to Guest machine. So that you can access guest machine through host machine.

Comment: `ip addr show` doesn't work on Windows 10.

Comment: for windows use `ipconfig`

Comment: alternative to ip addr show, you can just write ip a

Comment: I try to  ping 10.0.2.24 (inet)  (from ip addr show in the vm) but i get not response