# can't access to http://127.0.0.1:4200 after compiling npm start successfully

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I followed ng2-admin installation guidline https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/ on kaa sandbox ubuntu 14.04 launched on a virtuel box ,npm start compiled successfully but when i type this url http://127.0.0.1:4200 into the browser it doesn't work .i have ufw inactive, and the following versions:
git 1.9.1
npm 5.6.0
nodejs 9.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Try http://virtualboxip:4200.

it may work!

Try this URL to get info on Virtualbox ip details [how to get the ipaddress of a virtual box running on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953785/how-to-get-the-ipaddress-of-a-virtual-box-running-on-local-machine)

Comment: it doesn't work ,actually i dont think that it's an ip issue because when i launch http://127.0.0.1:9080 kaa Sandbox interface start, also when i run $netstat -l the 4200 doesn't exist