# Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server (from VM)

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to connect to mysql from a virtual Raspberry PI which I have running inside VirtualBoxVM.

Using a Python script:

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="MBP",
user="PI-2",
passwd="",
database="temperatureData"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO temperature (date, temp_celsius, temp_farenheit) 
VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
val = ("2019-01-14", "20")

mycursor.execute(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")
```

But fails with error:

```
1130: Host 'MBP' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

In Mysql (on my Macbook) I have set up a user by:

```
CREATE USER 'PI-2'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'PI-2';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'PI-2'@'127.0.0.1' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

(Using 127.0.0.1 since I'm using NAT inside VM - as mentioned here: [how to get the ipaddress of a virtual box running on local machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42953785/how-to-get-the-ipaddress-of-a-virtual-box-running-on-local-machine))

my.cnf file:

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]

# Only allow connections from localhost

# bind-address = 127.0.0.1

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

**Update:**

Output of `ifconfig` on MBP:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
[ ... ]
```

On VM:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:41:cb:b4
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::ef2d:bd28:6834:9191/64 Scope:Link


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
```

Comment: It seems to me that in mysql.connector.connect, the host should be '127.0.0.1' instead of MBP.

Comment: I did try that but then I get `2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111 Connection refused)` error @AnSe

Comment: I see. Could you please include output of `ifconfig` (or `ip addr show`) of Mac & VM in your original post?

Comment: Please see updated post @AnSe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grant privilege with this command : `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'PI-2'@'MBP' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

It allows MySQL to accept connection from a host named MBP.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html#grant-accounts-passwords